# building ionic3 cordova app for windows missing MakePri.exe

Tags: windows, cordova, build, msbuild

I have problems while building > ionic cordova build windows --release

```
>cordova build windows --release --arch="x64"
```

Building project: C:_DEV\ionic\5tgf\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : release
        Platform      : x64
  Patching 10 in prebuild event...
     C:\Program Files x86)\MSBuild \Microsoft \VisualStudio \v14.0 \AppxPackage \Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(912,5): error APP X1639:  fichier 'MakePri.exe' introuvable.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798187 for more information. 
[C:_DEV\ionic\5tgf\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1}

Link to microsoft is down, tried google without much result.
I ve tried to modify path variable by adding way to MakePri.exe

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64
```

Nothing work .. help me please :)